# How to get all maximal non-overlapping sets of spans from a list of spans

Tags: python, algorithm

I can't seem to find a way to write the algorithm in the title without needing to curate the results in some way.

To illustrate what I want:

```
all_spans = [(0, 5), (2, 7), (5, 8), (6, 10), (9, 10), (11, 15)]
possible_sets = [
    {(0, 5), (5, 8), (9, 10), (11, 15)},
    {(2, 7), (9, 10), (11, 15)},
    {(0, 5), (6, 10), (11, 15)}
]
not_possible = [
    {(0, 5), (5, 8), (6, 10), (11, 15)},  # has overlaps
    {(5, 8), (9, 10), (11, 15)}           # not maximal w.r.t possible_sets[0]
]
```

My current implementation is more or less this:

```
def has_overlap(a, b):
    return a[1] > b[0] and b[1] > a[0]

def combine(spans, current, idx=0):
    for i in range(idx, len(spans)):
        overlaps = {e for e in current if has_overlap(e, spans[i])}
        if overlaps:
            yield from combine(spans, current-overlaps, i)
        else:
            current.add(spans[i])
    yield current
```

But it produces non-maximal spans that I'd rather just not create in the first place.

```
>>> for s in combine(all_spans, set()):
...     print(sorted(s))
[(9, 10), (11, 15)]
[(6, 10), (11, 15)]
[(5, 8), (9, 10), (11, 15)]
[(9, 10), (11, 15)]
[(6, 10), (11, 15)]
[(2, 7), (9, 10), (11, 15)]
[(0, 5), (9, 10), (11, 15)]
[(0, 5), (6, 10), (11, 15)]
[(0, 5), (5, 8), (9, 10), (11, 15)]
```

Is there a different approach that avoids this behavior? I found similar problems under the keywords "interval overlaps" and "activity scheduling", but none of them seemed to refer to this particular problem.

Comment: How `{(5, 8), (9, 10), (11, 15)}  `is worse than `{(2, 7), (9, 10), (11, 15)}` ?

Comment: it's not worse, it's just invalid because there is a strictly bigger set: `{(0, 5), (5, 8), (9, 10), (11, 15)}`. There is no such strictly bigger valid set for `{(2, 7), (9, 10), (11, 15)}`

Comment: Is `{(0, 5), (9, 10), (11, 15)}` not also non-maximal? It seems like a subset of `{(0, 5), (5, 8), (9, 10), (11, 15)}`

Comment: @AndrewMcDowell Yep, typo on my part.

Comment: perhaps a list of sets is not the best data structure. A directional graph might be a better solution

Comment: @MaartenFabré Like [this](https://pastebin.com/uqreDggb)? It starts with the list of all spans and tries all possible shorter versions if it contains overlaps. It can be visualized as a graph, where every leaf is a valid set. They are also not minimal or unique though, but maybe it can be altered.

Comment: What does maximal refer to? The number of elements in the set or the difference from lowest number to highest or something else?

Comment: Number of elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by not wanting to curate the results.

You can filter out the non-maximal results after using your generator with:

```
all_results = [s for s in combine(all_spans, set())]

for first_result in list(all_results):
    for second_result in list(all_results):
        if first_result.issubset(second_result) and first_result != second_result:
            all_results.remove(first_result)
            break
```

To not produce them in the first place, you could do a check before yielding to see whether an answer is maximal. Something like:

```
def combine(spans, current, idx=0):
    for i in range(idx, len(spans)):
        overlaps = {e for e in current if has_overlap(e, spans[i])}
        if overlaps:
            yield from combine(spans, current-overlaps, i)
        else:
            current.add(spans[i])
    # Check whether the current set is maximal.
    possible_additions = set(spans)
    for item_to_consider in set(possible_additions):
        if any([has_overlap(item_in_current, item_to_consider) for item_in_current in current]):
            possible_additions.remove(item_to_consider)
    if len(possible_additions) == 0:
        yield current
```

Comment: Given `len(spans) = n` and `len(results) = m`, the complexity of the cleanup of the first approach is *O(m\*m)* and the prevention in the second is *O(n\*m\*m)*, so I'll stick to the first.

Comment: @Arne (if `len(spans) = n and len(results) = m`) I think mine is O(n * m). Does that seem right?

Comment: Better late than never: I chose the the filter approach, it produced the cleanest code and performed best with the kind of data that I have to handle.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple (?) graph problem.  Make a directed graph where each span is a node.  There is an edge AB (from node A to node B) iff A[1] <= B[0] -- in prose, if span B doesn't start until span A finishes.  Your graph would look like

```
Node    =>  Successors
(0, 5)  =>  (5, 8), (6, 10), (9, 10), (11, 15)
(2, 7)  =>  (9, 10), (11, 15)
(5, 8)  =>  (9, 10), (11, 15)
(6, 10) =>  (11, 15)
(9, 10) =>  (11, 15)
```

Now, the problem reduces to simply finding the longest path through the graph, including ties.

Given the linearity of the problem, finding one maximal solution is easier: at each step, pick the successor node with the soonest ending time.  In steps:

1. To start, all nodes are available.  The one with the soonest ending time is (0,5).
2. The successor to (0,5) with the earliest end is (5, 8).
3. The successor to (5,8) ... is (9, 10)
4. ... and finally add (11, 15)

Note that this much doesn't require a graph; merely a structure you're willing to reference by either first or second sub-element.

The solution length is 4, as you already know.

Can you take it form here?

Comment: Sure, I'll try to implement it (not today though) and will come back if I run into problems. Thanks for the post =)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming ranges are sorted by lower bound, we'd like to append the current range to the longest paths it can be appended to, or create a new path (append to an empty path). If it's called for, we could consider making the search for the longest prefixes more efficient. (The code below just updates that search in a slightly optimised linear method.)

(I'm not sure how to use the yield functionality, perhaps you could make this code more elegant.)

```py
# Assumes spans are sorted by lower bound
# and each tuple is a valid range
def f(spans):
  # Append the current span to the longest
  # paths it can be appended to.
  paths = [[spans.pop(0)]]
  for l,r in spans:
    to_extend = []
    longest = 0
    print "\nCandidate: %s" % ((l,r),)
    for path in paths:
      lp, rp = path[-1]
      print "Testing on %s" % ((lp,rp),)
      if lp <= l < rp:
        prefix = path[:-1]
        if len(prefix) >= longest:
          to_extend.append(prefix + [(l,r)])
          longest = len(prefix)
      # Otherwise, it's after so append it.
      else:
        print "Appending to path: %s" % path
        path.append((l, r))
        longest = len(path)
    for path in to_extend:
      print "Candidate extensions: %s" % to_extend
      if len(path) == longest + 1:
        print "Adding to total paths: %s" % path
        paths.append(path)

  print "\nResult: %s" % paths
  return paths

all_spans = [(0, 5), (2, 7), (5, 8), (6, 10), (9, 10), (11, 15)]

f(all_spans)
```

Output:

```py
"""
Candidate: (2, 7)
Testing on (0, 5)
Candidate extensions: [[(2, 7)]]
Adding to total paths: [(2, 7)]

Candidate: (5, 8)
Testing on (0, 5)
Appending to path: [(0, 5)]
Testing on (2, 7)

Candidate: (6, 10)
Testing on (5, 8)
Testing on (2, 7)
Candidate extensions: [[(0, 5), (6, 10)]]
Adding to total paths: [(0, 5), (6, 10)]

Candidate: (9, 10)
Testing on (5, 8)
Appending to path: [(0, 5), (5, 8)]
Testing on (2, 7)
Appending to path: [(2, 7)]
Testing on (6, 10)

Candidate: (11, 15)
Testing on (9, 10)
Appending to path: [(0, 5), (5, 8), (9, 10)]
Testing on (9, 10)
Appending to path: [(2, 7), (9, 10)]
Testing on (6, 10)
Appending to path: [(0, 5), (6, 10)]

Result: [[(0, 5), (5, 8), (9, 10), (11, 15)],
         [(2, 7), (9, 10), (11, 15)],
         [(0, 5), (6, 10), (11, 15)]]
"""
```